# How to implement OnMove() in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I've created a SDI MFC project and I'm trying to get it to refresh the coordinates of the window upon moving of the window...

Here's what I have so far:

```
// TODO: add draw code for native data here
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);

// Get window coordinates
int left = rect.left;
int right = rect.right;
int bottom = rect.bottom;
int top = rect.top;

// Print them out
CString l;
l.Format(L"%d", left);
pDC->TextOutW(0, 100, L"Left: " + l, _tcslen(l)+6);
CString r;
r.Format(L"%d", right);
pDC->TextOutW(0, 130, L"Right: " + r, _tcslen(r)+7);
CString b;
b.Format(L"%d", bottom);
pDC->TextOutW(0, 160, L"Bottom: " + b, _tcslen(b)+8);
CString t;
t.Format(L"%d", top);
pDC->TextOutW(0, 190, L"Top: " + t, _tcslen(t)+5);
```

What do I do to implement the onMove() function so that it refreshes these values with the new ones upon each move/resize of the window?

Comment: Adding drawing code to OnMove is a bad idea; just have it invalidate the window or some section of it, and draw what you need in OnPaint or OnDraw.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio to add callbacks for you, just go to the Properties for the class and add handlers for WM_MOVE and WM_SIZE.

Comment: @MarkRansom Properties for the class? Can you elaborate on what you mean by that? I right clicked on the MFCAppView.cpp file and went to properties...I didn't see any such option

Comment: I don't have any MFC projects handy anymore so I can't double-check for you, but isn't there a pane labeled events or messages or something?

Comment: @MarkRansom I have literally no clue....this is my first time using it

Comment: @MarkRansom OK. I got it.  I've added the message handler for WM_MOVE.  Now for the invalidation and redrawing of coordinates... How do I get access to the device context that OnCreate uses?

Comment: You don't. Just invalidate the window, and your existing OnPaint or OnDraw should already have access to the appropriate DC.